# String Matching in R - Problem with pattern

Tags: r, string, matching

I have a small Problem. I want to extract a special pattern like this:

v-97bcer
or b-chyfvg or ghd6db

I tried this:

```
identifier_1 <- "([:alnum:]{6})" # for things like this ghd6db
identifier_2 <- "([:lower:]{1})[- ][:alnum:]{6})" # for things like this v-97bcer or b-chyfvg
```

The problem is that the first "identifier" works well ok, but extracts for example names as well. In GHD6D8 this example the numbers have no fixed place and can occur everywhere. I do just now that the length is 6.

And the second problem is that for example V-97bcer can occur like v97bcer but I need this format v-97bcer. Here too the numbers are randomly.

If somebody could help or give me a good source for better understanding how to do this. I have not much exp in string matching. Thank you

Comment: What comes before and after these patterns?

Comment: Nothing I already removed all noninfo.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
x <- c("v-97bcer", "b-chyfvg", "ghd6db", "v97bcer")
grep("^([a-z].)?[a-z0-9]{6}$", x)
```

Note that in order to fix the length of the string I provide `^` and `$` to the string.

This pattern matches `v-97bcer` and `b-chyfvg` and `ghd6db` but not `v97bcer`.